# Cut or limit internet connection to other wifi devices

Tags: wireless

I used to use selfishnet in Windows to limit internet connection to others but now I can't find any alternative for it in Ubuntu.

I tried tuxcut but it doesn't show all connected devices in 14.04 and it doesn't even work in 16.04. I also made a small script with bash which get connected devices using `arp` then sends  DeAuth with `aireplay-ng`. This works but it's slow so when a lot of devices connect to wifi it does not really work.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 now and I am not the admin of router so i can't use QOS

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.ratelimit.single.html

Comment: hello,as i said i am new in linux . can give me something more simple ? thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ethtool

You can change the aggregate speed of the NIC port using `ethtool`.

```
$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 10
```

This will set the port to 10MB, for example.

### wondershaper

You can also use the tool `wondershaper` to do it as well. NOTE: Speed should be in kilobits per second.

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth1 downspeed upspeed
```

For example:

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth0 10000 280
```

### trickle

A 3rd option is `trickle`. Trickle can be used per program by users or as a daemon that throttles the NIC completely.

User mode - [trickle man page](https://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/trickle.1.txt)

```
$ sudo trickle -d 20 -u 20 wget http://www.google.com/bigfile
```

Will throttle 20K/s for both up and down traffic for just this `wget`, everything else will not be limited.

Daemon mode - [trickled man page](https://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/trickled.8.txt)

In daemon mode, trickled can limit a group of programs to a fixed limit of bandwidth. To start the daemon, run the trickled command:

```
$ sudo trickled -d 20 -u 20
```

### pyshaper

A 4th option is `pyshaper`. It's a unique option among the choices in that it includes GUI and it dynamically monitors and sets the bandwidth over time. You can check out the [pyshaper man page](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pyshaper/pyshaper.html)for more details.

Above copied from this answer: [StackExchange - limit outgoing bandwidth on a specific interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83888/limit-outgoing-bandwidth-on-an-specific-interface)